# Can you create the pstreams tag?

Tags: support, tag-creation

Please create the pstreams tag, to tag the relevant library:

[How to get the full stream output with pstreams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309020/how-to-get-the-full-stream-output-with-pstreams)
and for the other 2 questions mentioned in that question.

Thanks.

Comment: `p-streams` **ಠ_ಠ**

Comment: Related: [Can we please have the \[foo\] tag on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds reasonable, I added the tag to that question.

I didn't add it to the other questions since they don't seems to ask about pstreams specifically, even though pstreams might be a valid *answer* for them.