# When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?

Tags: support, faq, tags, tag-creation

Can someone please create the tag [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) on our site? We need to have it because

> - *Foo* is a recent/upcoming release / edition / model / episode of a popular, established OS / board game / bike brand / TV show
> - *Foo* is a hot new language / ingredient / game
> - we're currently using some other tag for questions about *Foo*, but it's causing ambiguity with a separate thing that's also named *Foo*

This is not a joke post. We get a lot of feature requests that ask for this or that tag to be created, and every time, a discussion ensues wherein people explain that there is no "tag creation department" and that community members create tags just by using them. I'm posting this "question" so that future requests of that type can be closed as a duplicate of this, saving time and eliminating redundant conversations for everyone involved.

> See also:
>
> - [Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions)
> - [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions)

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Answer (score 64):

### When should a tag be created?

Tags should only be created if there is a clear need for them, such as if it represents a new concept that has not been asked on the site before but is still on-topic for the site. For example, on Stack Overflow, if a new programming language has been created and is in wide use, but no one has asked any questions about it, a new tag should be created for it.

### When should I *not* create a tag?

- Don't create tags just for the sake of creating tags. You should use existing tags as much as possible, because people follow those existing tags, and this increases the likelihood of getting a good answer.
- Don't create tags that are [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), or tags that describe the nature of the question rather than its topic. Examples include [homework-problem](/questions/tagged/homework-problem) and [hard-question](/questions/tagged/hard-question).
- Don't create tags that are overly broad or ambiguous or cannot be used as the sole tag on any question. Examples include [first-edition](/questions/tagged/first-edition) or [version-2.0](/questions/tagged/version-2.0).
- Finally, don't create a tag if it violates any guidance on tag usage specific to the site, or goes against consensus established on the site's per-site meta (for instance, if the tag was removed after a community burninate discussion).

### How do I create a tag?

To create a tag, one must apply it to an existing question or a new question they're about to post. Any user with the [Create Tags privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (150 on sites with "beta" requirements, 300 on most sites with "full" requirements, 500 on Meta Stack Exchange, 1000 on Mathematics and Physics, and 1500 on Stack Overflow) may add new tags to any question at will<sup>1</sup>.

#### If you have enough reputation to create the tag

If you think there is a **clear need** for a tag, go ahead and create it yourself by typing the new tag into the question's tags field, and submitting the post or edit. If the new tag causes controversy, you can always come back to your site's meta to ask the community to judge it.

If you are creating a new tag, you may be prompted about it before you can submit your edit or new post. This warning is enabled on a site-specific basis.

**Note:** if there have been no questions asked about a certain topic you want to create a tag for, **please hold off on creating the tag** until you or someone else asks a relevant question about it. Don't just add the tag to a random question, and don't post a new "dummy" question just for the sake of creating the tag.

#### If you don't have enough reputation to create the tag

Ask your question with a [remotely related existing tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283028/2738262), and then **add a comment** on your question. Say that you wanted to add the tag to the question, but do not have enough reputation. Please consider including a reason *why* you think this tag is appropriate. If someone with enough reputation agrees with you, they will be able to create the tag. Please delete your comment once this has happened.

As an alternative, you can request a new tag by starting a discussion on the **per-site meta**. Clearly explain that you don't have enough reputation to create a new tag. This gives other people the opportunity to discuss if a new tag is needed.

<sup>1 *Exception: a small number of tags may have been [blocked from creation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blocked-tag) on your site because they're not suitable; these tags cannot be created.*</sup>

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any chance the tag blacklist is publicly available?

Comment: What would be a good definition of "**clear need**"?

Comment: @Bach in this context, "clear" is synonymous with "obvious." Granted, that's subjective, but users with enough reputation to create tags are expected to have good enough judgment to make those calls. And they're only tags anyways; the occasional mistakes aren't the end of the world.