# Request for a new tag: xtrf

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I represent [XTRF Management Systems](http://www.xtrf.eu/). Since 2005 our company has been working on a Translation Management System, called [XTRF](http://www.xtrf.eu/). In recent versions we've added XTRF API which enables users of our product to integrate with the system.

As people had started using our API, they started asking questions and encountering some problems. We have also received requests that people would like to put those questions and answers on StackOverflow but can't create **xtrf** tag. Unfortunately, none of our developers has 1500 reputation points, so we can't create it either.

Would it be possible for the **xtrf** tag to be added by a moderator?

Comment: As far as I know the current practice is not to create a tag unless there are questions for it. So your customers (or even your developers) should just start posting those questions and leave them non-tagged at the moment. They'll surely be re-tagged pretty quickly.

Comment: Alternatively: consider hiring some high-rep users from SO. The ability to create tags is probably the *least* of the advantages you'd get from that ;-)

Comment: Out of curiosity I checked if an XTRF-related question was asked and [found this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986799/cannot-invoke-any-operation-required-authentication-even-after-correct-log-in). I took the liberty to add [tag:xtrf].

Comment: A bit late, but see [Can we please have the \[foo\] tag on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a single (searchable) question on Stack Overflow about your product when searching with [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=xtrf+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=xtrf+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=serp.3...3460.3659.0.3868.3.3.0.0.0.0.173.235.2j1.3.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.E_PjYmF-x0I) or the [internal engine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xtrf).

I would argue that for this reason there is no need for anyone to create a new tag; especially as it'll be [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags).

If anyone does want to ask a question, and that question is on-topic, then if they have enough reputation they can create the tags themselves or flag that question for moderator attention/ask in the comments etc for someone else to create the tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation! We will encourage our API users to ask questions on SO, flag them and put a note with missing **xtrf** tag.

Comment: On a related note: googling for "XTRF API" doesn't lead to anything useful. I'm not aware of any official requirement to that effect, but experience tells me is that questions about publicly documented APIs usually get much better answers on SO. Consider making the API documentation publicly available.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Access to our [API documentation](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPI/Welcome+to+XTRF+API+Knowledge+Base) was restricted and available to our customers only. Today we have made a decision about making it public. We hope it will both make it easier for API user to find the documentation and speed up the process of building a strong community.

Comment: Nice to see you accepting Ben's answer.  Shows good grace and good will.

Answer (score 7):

Tags can't be created as stand-alone entities (except, I imagine, devs can do this directly in the database).  You need a question to attach the tag to.  If you post programming questions about using your API, a new tag can be created for it.