# Is it ok to add this tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we please have the [foo] tag on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so)

I'm working on a fun pair of programmable glasses called [BrightEyes](http://technologywillsaveus.org/bright-eyes-diy-kit/).
There are 3 options for programming:

- basic (using a media converter to put content on them)
- medium (programming using the Arduino IDE)
- advanced (going full AVR, attaching sensors, etc.)

I presume there will be questions about using them.
Is it safe/a good idea to create a `bright-eyes` tag on stackoverflow to follow ?

I expect most questions will be related to Arduino/Processing and specs specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New tags are created when they are applied to a question, you can't create a tag without having at least one relevant question first. When the first BrightEyes question appears, feel free to tag it as [bright-eyes](/questions/tagged/bright-eyes), assuming of course it will be an on topic question.

If you can think of a good question *now*, you might want to venture an [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) question - answer pair, however be warned:

- [The community frowns on overt self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion), you must clearly and unambiguously disclose your affiliation, and
- The community is generally tougher on self answered questions, if your question doesn't follow the normal guidelines it will be closed and possibly downvoted.

This is an extremely risky option, a badly formulated self answered question with a self promotion element will most certainly lead to a rain of downvotes on both the question and the answer. Up to you.

Comment: Wouldn't that be "*the community frowns on **covert** self promotion*"? We want them to be up front if they're self promoting.

Comment: @Asad No, overt (in the sense of obvious) is correct. If all you're doing is self promotion, and not, for example, also asking a useful to the wider community question, it doesn't really matter if you're upfront about it.

Comment: In that case the word "overt" shouldn't be there at all, since we frown *harder* at covert self promotion. I'm in a naggy mood today, sorry.

Comment: @Asad I agree it's a bit confusing, and if you post a feature request about changing the wording there, I'd upvote it.

Comment: I shall put one up post haste.

Comment: Thank you for going into the self-promotion issue as well. I have no problem explaining my affiliation and the main purpose of the tag isn't to promote the product itself, but to gather all questions relevant to the product under one group/tag. The tag description should detail how the users can program using the device, but shouldn't contain shameless self promotion.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I assumed as much after I took a quick look at your profile. I only added the second part of the answer after I saw that you have a ton of valuable contributions already, I wouldn't point you  to the self answer option if I was afraid you were yet another spammer or that you couldn't formulate a proper SO question.