# Request for tag [LiveCode]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

LiveCode has been a proprietary product of [RunRev](http://runrev.com) for quite some time. The community has been fairly small and to date there has been very little transfer over to StackOverflow. As a result of a recent successful [kickstarter campaign](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1755283828/open-source-edition-of-livecode) the platform will be going open source and I expect an influx of developers used to using StackOverflow and looking for an appropriate tag to subscribe to.

I would appreciate someone with the privilege creating the tag.

Some posts that require this tag [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272215/editing-polygon-points-with-livecode/15280243#15280243),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287597/how-do-i-calculate-the-location-of-the-selectedtext-with-a-livecode-field),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282065/why-wont-this-simple-livecode-ios-external-compile)... there's more. Basically it's a catch 22. I'm trying to encourage knowledgable people to answer questions on StackOverflow but many of them won't unless they can subscribe.

Comment: I can't find the dupe, but tl;dr: a tag can't exist without questions to add it to.  Once questions exist, the tag can be created.  e: [Ah, here's the dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146949/135887).

Comment: search for LiveCode there are questions there...

Comment: Could you link a few of them in your question?  Someone qualified to determine if they're worth tagging can help get the ball rolling.

Comment: I understand how tags are created. If nobody will do it I'll wait until I get the rep and do it but I thought it might be nice considering as you will see in my second example someone unhelpfully added iOS when the question was not iOS related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the [livecode](/questions/tagged/livecode) tag, added a short description to the tag and retagged questions I found searching for *LiveCode*.

Comment: very much appreciated, thanks