# Creating [pari-gp] as a separate tag from [pari]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The relationship between PARI and PARI/GP is a bit confusing. "GP" is a scripting language for the computer algebra system "gp". The purpose of GP (and gp) is to provide easy access to "PARI", which is a math library in C. So gp and GP don't exist without PARI, but PARI can exist without GP and gp.  This is explained [here](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/).

Given that GP doesn't exist without PARI, it's almost always referred to as PARI/GP, so [pari-gp](/questions/tagged/pari-gp) makes more sense than [gp](/questions/tagged/gp). This also avoids ambiguity between GP versus gp. Right now there is [pari](/questions/tagged/pari), but no [pari-gp](/questions/tagged/pari-gp). There are actually only fourteen questions with [pari](/questions/tagged/pari). These seven are actually about PARI/GP:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793890/how-to-make-multi-line-nested-for-loops-in-pari-gp) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943507/calling-pari-gp-from-python) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789491/pari-gp-user-defined-functions)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901501/how-to-get-the-total-length-of-a-row-vector-in-pari-gp)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024738/rounding-a-number-in-pari-gp)
[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176738/pari-gp-compare-integer-with-real)
[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947445/is-there-a-way-to-rationalize-a-decimal-in-pari-gp). IMHO these seven posts should be retagged [pari-gp](/questions/tagged/pari-gp). [I just read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so) and I would create [pari-gp](/questions/tagged/pari-gp) myself and retag the above posts, but I don't have the necessary 1500 rep. Could someone please retag the seven posts I linked to above, from [pari](/questions/tagged/pari) to [pari-gp](/questions/tagged/pari-gp)?

Comment: PARI/GP has really taken off as a programming language in the number theory community in the past few years. Unfortunately there's only a very small community for PARI/GP on SO. I emailed the PARI/GP developer about this today, who I have never met, and [he responded by joining SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2249606/k-b) and immediately answering six questions with needless to say very good answers.

Comment: I'm going to wait a few minutes to see if this gets moderator attention, but I agree this would be an improvement, esp. for StackOverflow purposes.

Comment: @hardmath Only half of the [tag:pari] posts (the seven linked in my question) should be changed to [tag:pari-gp]. The other seven should be left as [pari].

Comment: Okay, good thing I only changed those seven!  Actually someone was helping, starting from the other end of the list.

Comment: Great, it's perfect now! Thanks! This question should be closed as resolved now (?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seven questions identified have had pari tags converted to pari-gp, a new tag.

We should create a wiki text for this new tag (the older pari tag also lacks a wiki).

Comment: I've created first versions of tag wikis for [tag:pari] and [tag:pari-gp]. Someone had already written a short tag exerpt for pari-gp; I updated it with the description from the [PARI/GP website](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/). They're sitting in the queue now for review.