# accepted channels to request the addition of tags whilst not having the requisite reputation

Tags: discussion, tags

First of all: [Can we please have the [foo] tag on our site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so)

Now the question substance:

Is there an accepted channel for an unprivileged user to request the addition of a tag? If so, what is it? If not, is there a reason for its non-existence, and if so what is that reason?

Comment: I've seen people ask in their question for someone to create a tag for them. That's usually the best way as tags should be created for questions that need them, no just "because".

Comment: @Seth Agreed.  I managed to get the `[ewoks]` tag created on scifi.SE by asking in a question about Ewoks.  Can you _believe_ nobody ever asked about Ewoks before ;)

Comment: You don't say if the tag belongs on an existing question or one you intend to ask about

Comment: Seth's solution works well, because then the person who adds the tag can *also* remove your request to do so.