# New Tag request #Midori

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-creation

I would like to have the #Midori Tag. Since this browser comes with the common Raspian OS for Raspberry-Pi and there are many tutorials using #Midori . I think it makes sense to create the tag.

Comment: Just to be clear; is there an API for it?

Comment: did you read [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so)? What questions would you put it on?

Comment: [Some of these I'd guess](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=midori+is%3Aquestion) @nijansen.

Comment: mine :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544304/possible-to-let-raspberry-pi-display-2-websites-after-some-delay-in-kioskmode-u

Comment: Well it only takes one 500+ user to create a tag, and some people to peer-review editing it into questions. If it makes sense, it will happen anyway ;)

Comment: 1,5k+ user :) is needed :P

Comment: Well, it might be a good on-topic tag on SO, but I think not in the sense you meant. It would only make sense in regards to web development and browser specific issues. Except that it uses the Webkit engine, so you could use that tag instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I created it, [midori](/questions/tagged/midori), and a tag wiki for it, and added it to a few relevant questions.  It was logical since [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) and [opera](/questions/tagged/opera) and others already exist.