# I have a question I think is fit for scifi.SE, but it's not among tags. What now?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about Codex 632 by Jose Rodrigues Dos Santos. I think it might be a good fit for scifi.SE (if it is for Stack Exchange network), but I can't find it among tags. Which other site can I try?

Comment: What is it you can't find among the tags exactly? [Jose Rodrigues Dos Santos] would be too long as a tag name. Anyhow, I'd just drop in their chat and ask if my question is on-topic. There is a chance that you're the first person asking a question about that.

Comment: I think you should try asking it at [scifi.se]. Not finding a tag does not mean that it is not on-topic but be sure to read their help before asking.

Comment: I think you should probably ask this question on our Meta site, rather than the main site. The people here are experts in the general rules of Stack Exchange, but more over there know what is on-topic on our individual site.

Comment: And of course, even if our site is off-topic, the people on Sci-fi, Movies & TV,  or Writers are likely to have the domain knowledge necessary to answer your question anyway, so  you can always ask in chat.

Comment: Another possibility, given the subject matter of the novel, is that your question might be entirely historical in nature. If that is the case [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) might take it.

Comment: I don't know yet if it has historical pieces. Even if it has, my question has nothing to do with history.

Comment: Related; [Is Codex 632 on topic on SFF:SE?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10012/is-codex-632-on-topic-on-sffse?noredirect=1#comment28847_10012)

Answer (score 7):

First place to consult is, [the help page of Sci-fi and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which outlines which questions are on-topic there:

> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted
> towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes
> questions about:
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of a work
> - Behind-the-scenes and fandom information
> - Story identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order

But bear in mind, the Book you are asking the question about must either be of Science Fiction or Fantasy genre. The book must fit on following criteria:

1. It should have a plot based in Science Fiction or fantasy
2. Book's world should have magic/supernatural phenomena or advanced scientific technology
3. Book's world should have magical/supernatural or technologically advanced beings

If it doesn't fit this, then it would be off-topic there.

Other than that, Non-existence of a tag does not necessarily mean that the work is off-topic there.

You need 1500 reputation to create a tag on a Stack Exchange site. Assuming you don't have that much rep on Science Fiction and Fantasy SE, On a relevant [Meta Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-our-site) it is stated:

> If you do not have enough reputation to create the tag, then **ask the
> question with a remotely related existing tag, and then add a comment
> on your question. Say that you wanted to add the tag to the question,
> but do not have enough reputation**. Please consider including a
> reason why you think this tag is appropriate. If someone with enough
> reputation agrees with you, they will be able to create the tag.
> Please delete your comment once this has happened. As an alternative,
> you can request creating a tag by starting a new meta discussion. This
> gives other people the opportunity to discuss if a new tag is needed.

If you have that much rep, you can create the tag yourself.

You can view this [SFF Meta Post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10012/is-codex-632-on-topic-on-sffse) in response to your request where majority of users believe that Codex 632 is not on-topic on SFF.

In future however, if you want to discuss if something is on-topic or not for Sci-fi Stack Exchange, you are very welcome to come to [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42263/sff-on-topic-chat) and make your queries. You need 20 reputation to utilize the [chat privilege](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).