# Best practice in tag housekeeping re; tag assignments after tag creation?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, tag-creation

I read [When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146949/287826).  The relevant section says

> **If you have enough reputation to create the tag**
>
> If you think there is a clear need for a tag, go ahead and create it
>   yourself. If the new tag causes controversy, you can always come back
>   to your site's meta to ask the community to judge it.
>
> If you are creating a new tag, you may be prompted about it before you
>   can submit your edit or new post. This warning is enabled on a
>   site-specific basis.

My question is about what happens after I create the tag.  (To avoid swamping the active questions list, my personal guideline is to edit tags in small batches, e.g. half a dozen in 12 hours, in an established well-trafficked site, and more slowly in a Beta site.)

Example of a tag I plan to create:  I encountered a question on Academia that related to remote collaboration.  This is a thing in academia.  Surprisingly, at Academia SE we don't yet have a [remote-collaboration](/questions/tagged/remote-collaboration) tag.  I have enough rep to create it. This OP would benefit, I think, from reading other Q&A pages related to remote collaboration.  Once a bunch of questions have that tag, participants and visitors will have an easier time finding questions about that topic. (This was just an example.  A similar situation could come up on other sites.)

(A) Shall I wait, after creating the tag, before assigning the new tag to a first batch of relevant existing questions, in case there is an objection?

(B) Or is it better to assign the new tag to a small batch of questions right away, so others can see how I'm envisioning the new tag being used?

---

**Edit** to clarify:

- Please assume that if I am creating a tag, it's on a site that I know well.
- I was assuming I would create the tag by adding it to a question.  So from its inception, it would be associated with at least one question.
- The longest I would wait before beginning the small batch tagging process, as in (A), would be a couple of days or a week (depending on the pace of the particular site).  (Contrast this with Option B, where I would go ahead and tag a small batch of questions right after creating the tag.)

Comment: You probably shouldn't start an immediate spree of tagging existing posts with your newly created tags.

Comment: Just Do It but keep an eye on your active tab in case someone edit them out after you.

Comment: You can't create a tag without using it on at least one question. If you're not a regular user on the site, you might try gauging response in their chat before creating it. They may have a similar tag they use already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that **what you really want is more eyeballs on the proposed tag before you start applying it, in case there are objections.**

One can always write a meta post explaining the tag and listing several examples of the questions you intend to use it on.

The more lightweight solution is to ask some of the other users in chat, following the same basic formula.

Once the other eyeballs have looked over the proposed tag and agreed that it is needed I would go ahead and just start using it slowly.

This process just takes experience at judging whether a tag will be well received or not and who the people with strong opinions about tags are.

**For an exact time**

In either case, whether by meta or chat, I would wait at least **24 hours** as users are spread all around the globe and you can see what users in other time zones think of the tag.

Answer (score 5):

Aa you know, tags don't exist independently of questions, therefore to create a tag you have to add it to at least one question. As to how many questions you should add it to in one go, that depends on the site.

What you don't want to do is flood the home page with edited questions pushing new questions off the page. On a site like Stack Overflow where new questions come every few minutes this is less of a problem, but on lower traffic sites you should probably only do a handful at a time.

Tags that aren't used by any questions are effectively deleted overnight and don't get included in the autocomplete suggestions.

Tags that are only used by one question will get removed after a few months.

So, if you see the need for a tag by all means add it to a question or two, but don't go mad and add it to questions for the sake of it.

Comment: ChrisF - thanks for posting but my question is focused on *when* to make the first batch of tag edits.  I could jump in and do the first batch upon creating the tag (by adding it to a question), or I could wait.  (I agree that the pace would depend on the level of traffic of the site to avoid swamping the active list.)