# Should you ask a Stack Exchange Community if it wants a certain tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-creation

Suppose you went a Stack Exchange community (lets use Stack Overflow as an example) and intended to ask a question. However, you want to use a tag that you now discover does not exist. You have enough reputation to create the tag, but you are not sure if Stack Overflow **wants** the tag itself, as it is either not a commonly known subject or it may be seen as an advertisement. Your question is not reliant on this tag, but there might be some confusion if you don't include it.

So now here is what I want to know: **Would you ask the community the question of whether they wanted the tag?** If you were to do this, you would know whether or not the community wanted the tag, but on the other hand, it would be kind of a meta-question, as it was about the site itself. So would it be ethical or against regulations?

Comment: This is answered in our FAQ [When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-should-i-create-a-new-tag-how-do-i-request-a-new-tag-if-i-dont-have-enoug), in the sentence beginning with *As an alternative*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/282094) - `Your question is not reliant on this tag, but there might be some confusion if you don't include it.` - Search for the text: Don't use tags that are not about your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a question about tag creation you'd ask it on the per site Meta. For Stack Overflow that would be [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Each site has its own meta apart from this one which is the global meta for all sites and is for question that affect all sites. So Meta Stack Exchange is the exception, if you want to create a tag here then you'd actually ask about it here.

If you don't have enough rep to create a tag you can ask for it to be created. Sites have [meta questions that detail the process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work).

You can even ask if you have enough rep to create a tag. Maybe you're unsure what to put in the Wiki or the Wiki Excerpt, or exactly what to name the tag.

Here's [an example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/414998/merge-cmake-custom-command-and-add-custom-command) of someone with nearly 100K reputation asking for advice on tag creation/naming.