# What is the right place to discuss adding or modifying tags for a given site?

Tags: support

Where should I go to discuss adding, merging, renaming, or deleting tags, whether or not I have enough rep to do so myself, on a particular site?

Here is an example of a question that might get asked (it's a real question I have):

> On https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, there is currently no
> `block-themes` tag. Should we create one, or is it better to combine
> `theme-development` and `block-editor` for questions related to block
> themes?

Comment: @JiminyCricket This clarifies the answer given by Elements in Space. Why do comments that sound like full answers, like this, get created under the question?

Comment: Per our FAQ [When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-should-i-create-a-new-tag-how-do-i-request-a-new-tag-if-i-dont-have-enoug): *As an alternative, you can request a new tag by starting a discussion on the per-site meta. Clearly explain that you don't have enough reputation to create a new tag. This gives other people the opportunity to discuss if a new tag is needed.*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer that. I never bothered to ask about it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask on the meta of the site that the tag you which to discuss.  Tag the question with *tag*, *discussion*, and possibly the relevant tag  (if it exists).

In particular, ask your WordPress tag question at [WordPress: Meta](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com).